# Mask a specific area in contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

im wondering if anyone have any idea how to mask or hide a specific area in a contour plot in python, here is a part of my code

```
    self.fig=plt.figure()
    delta = 0.025
    xmin=4
    xmin=6
    x=np.arange(4,6,delta)
    ymin=85
    ymax=91
    y = np.arange(85, 91, delta)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z=formel()//here im using a specific formula to calculate Z
    plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.16)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    self.CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
    plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
    plt.ylim(ymin, ymax)
    plt.plot(pointX, pointY, 'kx')
    plt.clabel(self.CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().config(width=400,height=400)`
```

here is how I want to mask the areas 
[image]
thank you guys

Comment: Please adjust your question to have a MCVE as currently the code snippet won't run, because quite some things are missing (e.g. `formel`,`x`,`y` and `delta`).

Comment: i edited the question but I didn't write the formel cause it is long and it won't make any sense here. Hopefully this was what you meant when you asked to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `PathPatch` to display your mask over the top as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath

ax = plt.gca()

x = np.linspace(0.04, 0.06, 100)
y = np.random.random(100) * [0.91 - 0.85] + 0.85

top, right, bottom, left = y.max(), x.max(), y.min(), x.min()
mask_height = (top - bottom) * 0.4      # 40% mask coverage

plt.plot(x, y, zorder=1)

ax.set_xlim(left, right)
ax.set_ylim(bottom, top)

path_data = [
    (mpath.Path.MOVETO, (left, bottom)),
    (mpath.Path.LINETO, (right, bottom)),
    (mpath.Path.LINETO, (left, mask_height + bottom)),
    (mpath.Path.CLOSEPOLY, (0,0)),

    (mpath.Path.MOVETO, (right , top)),
    (mpath.Path.LINETO, (right, top - mask_height)),
    (mpath.Path.LINETO, (left, top)),
    (mpath.Path.CLOSEPOLY, (0, 0)),
    ]

codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, facecolor=(0.8, 0.8, 0.8), lw=2, ec=(0.8, 0.8, 0.8), zorder=2)#, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show()
```

This would give you something like:

[image: plot with mask]

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, im going to give it a try.

Comment: I have updated it to automatically calculate `path_data` based on the data.

Comment: Hey, i get an Error  saying 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Are you testing my script "as is", or have you made a change?  It should work fine.

Comment: No I actually changed it a bit, I will try it as is now

Comment: It works, I guess I must change something in my code and try to make it work. Anyway thank you for your answer.